# Marking a Form Element as Required Inside an EventSubscriber in symfony2

Tags: symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have an entity with a member called 'mediaType', which tells me which of two other members to pull data from. When I'm building the form to create the entity, I have mediaType as a drop down and then two text fields for the other two members. What I want to do is force one or the other two fields to be required based on the mediaType selected (or neither, if the user select None. I'll handle hiding the fields with JS).

Since I'm manipulating the form after binding, I set up an EventSubscriber to listen on the PostBind event. My subscriber fires just fine, but I'm at a loss to figure out how to mark one of the fields as required. I can get the field, and I can check to see if it is required, but I just don't know how to make it required.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way than using EventSubscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use validations groups http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups see "Groups based on Submitted Data"